# Why am I getting two different sets of coordinates from parsing a pdf file?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdf-parsing

So, I am trying to parse a PDF file (30000x2000 points), using Python, that has all kinds of data on it, tables, lines, text, notes, images, etc. **The goal**: find a certain text string on the pdf and return a note that is a proximity to the text. I am using **PyPDF2** to find all the notes and their coordinates. To find text strings and their coordinates I am using **fitz**.

**Using fitz, I searched for 'A715_X1'.**

```
import fitz    
doc = fitz.open(path_pdf)
    for page in doc:
        coordinates_of_item_found_on_print = page.search_for('A715_X1')
```

**Result:  X coordinate: 9076 points**

**Then, using PyPDF2, I searched for the 'Some text here' note.**

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader(sample.pdf)
for page in reader.pages:
    if "/Annots" in page:
        for annot in page["/Annots"]:
            obj = annot.get_object()
            markup_coordinates = obj['/Rect']
            if obj['/Subtype'] == '/FreeText': # skip Stamp, Popup, Square, PolyLine
                if obj['/Contents'] == 'Some text here':
                    try:
                        markup_loc.append(str(round(markup_coordinates[0])))
                        print('Note: ' + obj['/Contents'] + ' X-coord: ' + str(round(markup_coordinates[0])))
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
```

**Result: Note: Some text here X-coord: 4280**

I attached a screenshot from PDFXchange showing 'A715_X1' right below the 'Some text' note, so the X coordinates should be roughly the same +- a couple of points. By looking at the print, 9076 seems like a "real" value according to the ruler lines. So why am I getting two different coordinates?

Example pdf:

[image: example pdf]

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

Comment: @MartinThoma, thank you for pointing out, but I am getting the same result.

Comment: PyMuPDF / fitz uses a coordinate system with origin (0, 0) located at the page's top-left. Whereas PDF (any several other packages) use the bottom-left point as origin. In PyMuPDF, each page has a property `page.transformation_matrix` that does the transformation between the coordinate system. In PyMuPDF, you can use normal algebra for calculation like so: `fitz_point = pdf_point * page.transformation_matrix`, or exactly the same for PyMuPDF and PDF rectangles. The inverse of a matrix is `~matrix`, you can multiply / divide matrices `m1 * m2`, or `m1 / m2` etc.

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for their help. @KJ, getting a coefficient out of page size / 14400 does work. I haven't tested it on a different file yet, but at least I have a starting point now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your minimal sample I had to emulate a blank file, luckily your image gives enough info for trial and error to calculate positions and orientation.

So here is that emulation. We can see the /MediaBox size is identical. That horizontal dimension is outside the allowed size for a traditional page, and thus Acrobat kept complaining at my earlier attempts.

I went through a dozen attempts to get it closest to yours. Clearly my annotation will be slightly different without your existing transformation but I am within a few points.

[image]

So what did I know and learn in the attempt to get the correct differentials ?

1. I know a page traditionally cannot be wider than 14,400 points. Thus to emulate a larger Space we need to scale that size media upwards and thus in this case that maximal 14400 (PaperSpace) is allocated a UserUnit of 2.12

Emulated values should be close to OP units.

```
12 0 obj
<</Annots[14 0 R]/Contents 15 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 14400 1124.15]/Parent 6 0 R/Resources<</ExtGState<</GS0 16 0 R>>>>/Type/Page/UserUnit 2.12>>
endobj
```

Now we can see, that if we multiply the annotations true placement (4281pt without scale) by that scalar we get 4281x2.12=9,075.72 which is the NOMINAL offset in X for the top left-hand corner in the scaled /Media.

Annotations (including form fields) in effect, are not tied in any way to the scale or the datum of the page contents. They can have their own co-ordinate scalar values and thus scaling/rotating/moving the page content will often break the relative placements. Luckily in this case they are using a known historic system.

Comment: @K J, Thank you for the extended answer. I really appreciate the effort. The whole pdf parsing subject is new to me and i still learn new aspects of it. I will try a new approach tomorrow.